# Can the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty q^{F_n}$ be expressed in terms of theta functions?

Tags: special-functions, power-series, theta-functions

Let $F_0=0,F_1=1,...$ be the Fibonacci numbers. Is there a known closed form for the sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty q^{F_n}$? By closed form, I mean in terms of well-known functions, the first ones to think of would probably be theta functions.

The fact that $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{F_n}$ diverges everywhere makes me rather pessimistic, but maybe this series has been studied somewhere?

Comment: Well, what is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty q^{2^n}?$ If you can't find a closed form (of any sort) for that, good luck with Fibonacci numbers...

Comment: What Igor said.  Theta functions are like $\sum_n q^{n^2}$ and not $\sum_n q^{c^n}$

Comment: At least $f(q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{2^n}$ has a functional equation
$f(q) = q + f(q^2)$.  
Does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{F_n}$ have anything like that?

Comment: @Noam: Note that the sequence $2^n$ is a sequence with first order recurrence relation, so the functional equation for $f(q)$ should only involve itself. By analogy, because the sequence $F_n$ is a second order recurrence, there ought to be some functional equations in terms of $U(q) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty q^F_n$ and $V(q) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty q^L_n$ with $L_n$ the Lucas sequence. I haven't been able to get very far with trying to construct an explicit functional equation from these though (lots of terms that don't immediately cancel and whatnot).

Comment: @ Igor & ARupinski: I remember having read an article featuring the sum you mention. I think it was about functions that don't have an analytic continuation beyond the unit circle. If my memory serves, it was rather interested in asymptotics than in a closed form.

Comment: @ Gerald: I didn't look at it like that. I rather had in mind the fact that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{ \infty} 1/F_{2k+1}$ can be cast in terms of theta functions (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html). It might be easier to start with $\sum_{k=0} ^{ \infty} q^{F_{2k+1}}$, as the odd Fibonacci numbers are "symmetric".